# How to use NEON optimization for ARM in libpng 1.5.x, I received link errors

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, neon, libpng

I found optimization for NEON in pngrutil.c. But when I define a macro "PNG_ARM_NEON" and try to compile the sources in android NDK, I get these link errors:

```
/libpng/pngrutil.c:3730: undefined reference to `png_read_filter_row_up_neon'
/libpng/pngrutil.c:3730: undefined reference to `png_read_filter_row_sub4_neon'
/libpng/pngrutil.c:3730: undefined reference to `png_read_filter_row_avg4_neon'
/libpng/pngrutil.c:3730: undefined reference to `png_read_filter_row_paeth4_neon'
/libpng/pngrutil.c:3730: undefined reference to `png_read_filter_row_sub3_neon'
/libpng/pngrutil.c:3730: undefined reference to `png_read_filter_row_avg3_neon'
/libpng/pngrutil.c:3730: undefined reference to `png_read_filter_row_paeth3_neon'
```

I found that these functions are declared in "pngpriv.h", but couldn't find the implementations in any source file.

Is the "NEON Optimization" already available for use in current version of libpng or just   "TODO"?

Comment: I can see they are in arm/filter_neon.S. How do you build libpng? did you add arm/filter_neon.S to your Android.mk?